# retrieve a field from database table using symfony doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to create an api to retrieve a field from the database using symfony2 doctrine but the query keeps returning a result not found. This is my attempt

```
 /**
 * @Route("/get/{email}")
 */
 public function emailAction($email)
 {
   $singleresult = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Api3Bundle:Influ')->find($email);
   if ($singleresult === null) {
   return new View("user not found", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
   }
```

Please how can I modify the above url so that on calling the uri endpoint let it return the email in the argument.

Comment: Please read [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Try ->findOneBy(array('email' => $email)) instead of ->find($email)

Answer (score 0):

If in you entity has a field named "Email", you could use findOneByEmail(), it is a dynamic method names to find a single object based on a column value:

```
->getRepository('Api3Bundle:Influ')findOneByEmail($email);
```

You can also use findOneBy() method to easily fetch objects based on multiple conditions,for example you want to retrieve an email but just if it is active, in that case you could pass and array:

```
->getRepository('Api3Bundle:Influ')findOneBy(
        array('email' => $email, 'active' => 1)
);
```